# Selenium RC - HtmlRunnerTestLoop Undefined - user-extensions.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

I am having a hell of a time getting Selenium RC to run my data-driven tests correctly via a batch file. The scripts were written via the Selenium IDE and use features such as if, while, xml and label and are working just fine within the IDE. I have scoured the internet trying to find a working user-extensions.js file, but to no avail.

I have a "somewhat" working version I found on here (stackoverflow), but I keep getting an HtmlRunnerTestLoop is undefined error.

The script will run through it's first iteration just fine, but then at the end the command prompt says, "Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully" and shuts down.

When I try to load that .js file directly into Selenium IDE, I get the error saying that HtmlRunnerTestLoop is undefined.

Does anybody have a working user-extensions.js file that includes the SelBlocks/Flow Control plugins they could share or point me too? Or have any suggestions for that matter?